# Error:value recallAt is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RankingMetrics[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

I want to calculate recall@25 and F1-score@25 by using ranking metrices.

```
val predictionAndLabels = predicted.
    select($"prediction",$"label")
    .as[(Double, Double)]
val Arr = predictionAndLabels.rdd.map(x => (Array(x._1),Array(x._2)))
val matrix = new RankingMetrics(Arr)
Array(1, 25).foreach { k =>
  println(s"Recall at $k = ${matrix.recallAt(k)}")
}
      Array(1, 25).foreach { k =>
  println(s"F1-score at $k = ${matrix.F1scoreAt(k)}")
}
```

Error:

> value recallAt is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RankingMetrics[Double]

How to solve it?

Comment: What is the spark version that you are using?

Comment: I used spark version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think `recallAt` method was not defined in spark 2.0.2 which can be seen [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/RankingMetrics.scala):

```
@Since("3.0.0")           // note this, it was defined at spark 3.0.0
  def recallAt(k: Int): Double = {
    require(k > 0, "ranking position k should be positive")
    predictionAndLabels.map { case (pred, lab) =>
      countRelevantItemRatio(pred, lab, k, lab.toSet.size)
    }.mean()
  }
```

You can use this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#threshold-tuning) to calculate recall and fscore for spark 2.0.2

Let me know if it helps!!